# Letting a user create more than 1 object

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that lets the user create 2 depots.
I have it in a switch statement, but when it completes and I go back to create the second depot it overwrites depot1.

I'm not sure how I'd go about creating 2 separate depots.

```
do {
    System.out.println("(1) Add depot number 1 ");
    System.out.println("(2) Remove a depot");
    System.out.println("(3) Exit program");
    option = console.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1: 
            depot1 = new Depot();                           
            if (depot1.checkDepot() == true){
                System.out.println("Enter Depots name");
                n = console.next();
                depot1.setDepotName(n);                                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error only 2  depots allowed");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
while (option !=3);
```

```
public class Depot 
{
   private String name;
   private Product product1, product2, product3;
   static int depotCounter = 0;

   // Constructor to count depot objects 
    public Depot(){
        depotCounter++;
    }
   // Method to make sure no more than 2 depots are created
    public boolean checkDepot(){
        if (depotCounter <= 2){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
```

Is my depot class, I have a counter and a checkdepot to make sure only 2 get created.

It creates depot1 fine, but when I go into the statement again and click (1) it re-writes a new name over the object depot1

Comment: I cant use arrays too, sorry should have added that.

Comment: Could you show the Depot-class as well? And any reason why you don't just use two parameters depot1 and depot2 and as soon as both are initialized stop creating new ones?

Comment: Whats the logic inside checkDepot?

Comment: Added that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter option 1, all it does is execute the code in the first "switch-case". And in there, you always use depot1 as variable. By the way, after you exit the switch statement, your depot gets lost anyways, because you declare it in that block. What you could do, is something like this:

```
do {
    Depot depot1;
    Depot depot2;
    //Your code for the menu, e.g. selecting what the user wants to do
    switch (option) {
        case 1 :
            if (depot1 == null) {
                depot1 = new Depot()
                //Do what you want to do with your depot
            } else if (depot2 == null) {
                depot2 = new Depot()
                //Same as above
            }
            break;
            //Rest of the switch statement
    }
} while (option != 3)
```

What I did there, is just use 2 different variables for the depots, and when you want to create a new depot, you first check if you already created a depot (if e.g. depot1 points at some object, so if depot1 == null is false) and then create the corresponding depot. If you haven't created a depot at all, then depot1 IS null, so you create depot1. If you already created depot1, depot1 == null is false, so it jumps to the second if-block, checks if depot2 is null, it is, so it creates depot2. When there already are 2 depots, it does nothing.

If you want more than 2 depots, what Backpack says in his answer is your way to go.

To summarize: 
a) You need different variables for your depots, not only one, so you don't just overwrite your current depot. 
b) If you want your objects to persist outside of the switch statement, you need to declare them outside of it. Variables only "live" inside the block, that you declare them in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a list of **depots** and just iterate through them. That way you can add an object whenever you please to the list, or delete it from the list.

Also, you can add an identifier in the **depot** object, that gives like an ID or something so you can differentiate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int option = 0;
        Depot depot;
        String name;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Depot> depotList = new ArrayList<>();
        do {

            System.out.println("(1) Add depot number ");
            System.out.println("(2) Remove a depot");
            System.out.println("(3) Exit program");
            if (console.hasNextInt()) {
                option = console.nextInt();

                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        if (depotList.size() < 2) {
                            System.out.println("Enter new Depot name:");

                            if (console.hasNext()) {
                                name = console.next();
                                depot = new Depot();
                                depot.setDepotName(name);
                                depotList.add(depot);
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Error only 2  depots allowed");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // remove depot code
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                }
            }
        } while (option != 3);

        System.out.println("Depots added:");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        depotList.forEach(currentDepot ->
            System.out.println(currentDepot.getDepotName()));
```